# make checkbox disabled in asp.net mvc 2 and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

i got a checkbox that i would like to be disabled ? i am using asp.net mvc 2 and jquery.

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(p=>p.flag) %>
```

---

```
public class MyModel
{
  public bool flag {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: have you thought of using `Html.CheckBoxFor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can either use jquery to disable your checkbox using

```
$('#flag').attr('disabled', true);
```

or if you want to do it on server side you have to fall back to checkboxfor helper like

```
<%:Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.flag, new { disabled = "disabled" }) %>
```

or you can write your own editor template that can consume additionalViewData parameter of `Html.EditorFor`

Comment: the first option requires Javascript. The second option is the better way to go.

Comment: yep second one is certainly better