# ASP.NET MVC3 @Html.EditorFor Checkbox disable enable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working in ASP.NET MVC3 using Razor. I have a situation where I want to enable disable a checkbox based on a boolean property. My model class has 2 properties like:

```
public bool IsInstructor { get; set; }
public bool MoreInstructorsAllowed { get; set; }
```

Now in my cshtml file, I am showing the checkbox as:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsInstructor)
```

I want this checkbox to enable disable on basis of MoreInstructorsAllowed property.
Thanks in advance for the solution. :)

Comment: I saw a solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590663/make-checkbox-disabled-in-asp-net-mvc-2-and-jquery    but I want to use EditorFor instead of CheckBoxFor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EditorFor` extension method wires up your Model to the PartialView that is located in the EditorTemplates file that corresponds to the type of the Model (so in this case, it would need to be `Boolean.cshtml`).

You can accomplish your objective by adding conditional logic to the Editor Template.  You will also need to give the partial a way to know what value the `MoreInstructorsAllowed` property has, and you can use the `EditorFor` overload with the `additionalViewData` parameter to pass this information.

Honestly, changing the default functionality of processing booleans seems like its a little much for what you are trying to do.  If these two fields are fundamentally linked, it would make more sense to make a composite of the two fields and wire up a partial view to the composite rather than the to the booleans themselves.  What I mean is:

```
public class InstructorProperty { 
    public bool IsInstructor { get; set; }
    public bool MoreInstructorsAllowed { get; set; }
}
```

and in */Shared/EditorTemplates/InstructorProperty.cshtml*

```
@model InstructorProperty

//  ...  Your view logic w/ the @if(MoreInstructorsClause) here.
```

The only problem is that now you are back at the problem of having to use the `CheckboxFor` method in order to  apply the "disabled" attribute, because the `EditorFor` methods don't accept ad hoc html attributes.  There is a known work around that involves overriding your `ModelMetadataProvider` and decorating the property with an attribute that you provide handling for in the ModelMetadataProvider.  A working example of this technique is available at: [http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-*2D00*-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx) .  However, that's still going to involve either: (1) overriding the Boolean view and either hard-coding the html or using CheckboxFor in there, (2) using a `CheckboxFor` method in the `InstructorProperty` view, or (3) hard-coding the html into the `InstructorProperty` view.  I don't think it makes sense to over complicate design for such a trivial thing, so my solution would be to use this `InstructorProperty` view and just add:

```
@Html.CheckboxFor(_=>_.IsInstructor, 
    htmlAttributes: (Model.MoreInstructorsAllowed ? null : new { disabled = "disabled"} ).ToString().ToLowerInvariant() });
```

But I get that everyone has different styles...  One other side note.  If your aversion to using the Checkbox method is related to the generated naming scheme, the way that the Mvc Framework accesses this feature involves `html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)`

Comment: thanks a lot for this detailed reply, but if we use CheckboxFor, than MoreInstructorsAllowed property will have to be string? as disabled attribute can't be true or false, it can be disabled and enabled.

Answer (score -1):

```
@if (Model.MoreInstructorsAllowed) 
  { 
//if MoreInstructorsAllowed true then checkbox IsInstructor not disabled
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsInstructor)
  }
  else
  {
//else MoreInstructorsAllowed false then checkbox IsInstructor will disabled
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsInstructor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "disabled" } })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already an accepted answer that's been validated by the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?