# Disable other CheckBoxes if one CheckBox is checked in GridView ItemTemplate in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two check boxes in grid view created using item template.
i want to disable other check box if one is selected in grid view.

Gridview code:-

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approved">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApprove" Text="Approved" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rejected">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRejected" Text="Rejected" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Javascript code:-

```
    function CheckBox_Clicked(chk) {
      var grid = chk.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
      var chks = grid.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
        if (chks[i].type == "checkbox" && chks[i] != chk) {
          chks[i].disabled = chk.checked;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: @Prakash - BTW any restrictions in using jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC3 @Html.EditorFor Checkbox disable enable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910548/asp-net-mvc3-html-editorfor-checkbox-disable-enable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it with jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[id*="chkApprove"]').change(function () {
       var currentRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
       $('input[id*="chkRejected"]', currentRow).attr('disabled', this.checked);
    });

    $('input[id*="chkRejected"]').change(function () {
       var currentRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
       $('input[id*="chkApprove"]', currentRow).attr('disabled', this.checked);
    });
});
```

**Code Explanation**:-

I am using the jQuery[Ends with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) attribute selector to get the `chkRejected` checkbox because it's ID will be rendered as `GridView1_chkApprove_0` and registering the change event. Inside this I am finding the containing row (since gridview is rendered as HTML table) and finally selecting the other checkbox (present inside same row) and disabling it.